# Is there a tool to auto-restore network shares?

Tags: macos, network, smb

I log on to my work VPN very infrequently. Whenever I do that, I have to painfully re-connect manually to all the network shares I use there.

Is there a tool (preferably with a UI) that can help me with this small but persistent inconvenience?

(Alternatively, is there a way to keep network shares in finder and re-connect to them with one click?)

Answer (score 1):

## [Sidekick](http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/) by Oomph

I use an app called Sidekick.  It mounts my drives, printers and other network devices automatically.  I have multiple configs for multiple networks and it automatically mounts what I need based on the network it senses.

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. Is it easy to set up? Got a screenshot or short set of instructions, perhaps?  Does it re-connect the servers automatically if they get disconnected?